# How do I reverse every string in a string array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

```
public static void reverse(String[] array){
    String reverse = "";
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        for(int j = array[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; i--)
        {
            reverse = reverse + array[i].charAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this method I am trying to reverse every single string in the string array but it just throws an exception. The array's length and elements are being inputed with scanner.

```
public static String[] arrayStringCreation(String[] array){
        boolean isArrayInputStillGoing = true;
        while (isArrayInputStillGoing){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Input the size of the array");
            int sizeOfArray = scanner.nextInt();
            if (sizeOfArray <= 0){
                System.err.println("Size can't be less than 1");
                continue;
            }
            array = new String[sizeOfArray+1];
            System.out.println("Input words less than 20 symbols");
            for(int i=0;i<sizeOfArray+1;i++){
                array[i] = scanner.nextLine();
                if (array[i].length()>20){
                    System.err.println("Try again with a word with less than 20 symbols");
                    i--;
                }
            }
            isArrayInputStillGoing=false;
        }
        return array;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `array[i].charAt(j)`? Also, you're never resetting reverse to `""`

Comment: FYI: `char` type in Java is obsolete. Use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) numbers instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't update the array with the reverse string and decrement `j` in the inner loop

```
    public static void reverse(String[] array) {
        String reverse;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            reverse = "";
            for (int j = array[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                reverse += array[i].charAt(j);
            }
            array[i] = reverse;
        }
    }
```

, main

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String arr[] = { "head", "body", "hand" };
        reverse(arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
```

, output

```
[daeh, ydob, dnah]
```

Comment: yeah thanks I did that and it worked but the main problem was that I was inputing by error a null array and not the one I had created with scanner.

Comment: Caution: **This code fails** with more than half of the characters defined in Unicode. See a failing example of this code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/U14rKs). The `char` type in Java is obsolete. Use Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) numbers instead. For a robust solution, see the [Answer by Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61877774/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque I have corrected the posted code in the question and it's simple for the **ASCII**

Comment: Expecting only ASCII characters is not very realistic. So too expecting only [*Basic Multilingual Plane*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) is not very realistic. Even ignoring foreign languages, the use of certain symbols and emojis will break this code. In the year 2020, it really is time to learn how to use code point numbers rather than `char` type.

Answer (score 4):

## `StringBuilder::reverse`

Simply iterate the array, and replace each entry with its reverse. You can use a `StringBuilder` to reverse a `String`, calling [`StringBuilder.reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()).

Like,

```
public static void reverse(String[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = new StringBuilder(array[i]).reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

And then to test it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String arr[] = { "abc", "def" };
    reverse(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/WsigRX).

> [cba, fed]

Comment: I tried using that but I still get the same exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @NotJhonWick45 that must be because there are nulls in the array.

Comment: When I create the array it prints out the contents and they are the same as I have inputed I don't see any nulls

Comment: @NotJhonWick45 The first line of the stack trace should tell you exactly which line is throwing the nullpointerexception. Are you certain the exception is from this method? Post a reproducible example. Because this code will reverse `String`(s).

Comment: at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:112)

Comment: @NotJhonWick45 that indicates a `NullPointerException` in the constructor of `StringBuilder`, which means you're passing it the value `null`.

Comment: So maybe it is my scanner method I am using? I will edit the post and post it too,

Comment: nvm the error was in another place where I was indeed inputing a null array and not the array I had created. Sorry for waisting your time...

Comment: @NotJhonWick45 See my version of the code presented in this Answer [on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/WsigRX). There you will find a couple of checks looking for null values. The checks were made by calling [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,java.lang.String)). If the value in question is indeed null, an exception is thrown. The exception carries a message of your authorship. When writing a method such as `reverse` that is meant to be called from other places, it is generally best to verify all inputs.

Comment: @NotJhonWick45 By the way, Java 14 has new and improved `NullPointerException` ([JEP 358](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/358)) to help locate such problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StringUtils.reverse](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#reverse-java.lang.String-) of `org.apache.commons.lang3` from the [*Apace Commons*](http://commons.apache.org) project. That method handles `null`.

```
public static void reverse(String[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = StringUtils.reverse(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: it says "Cannot resolve method reverse in StringUtils"

Comment: Maybe you didn't import `StringUtils`.

Comment: @NotJhonWick45 This Answer uses a library from Apache Commons. You will need to obtain that library and add to your project to utilize this approach.

Answer (score 1):

## Stream

The [Answer by Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61877774/642706) is correct and robust, and should be accepted.

In addition, for fun, here is a version of that code using streams rather than the conventional `for` loop. I am *not* claiming this is better.

I do not know of a way for a stream of an array to affect that array. So instead here I make and return a fresh array.

```
public static String[] reverse( String[] array ) {
    Objects.requireNonNull( array , "Received null argument where an array of `String` was expected. Message # b5c03336-4b9e-4735-a054-16e43aac059e.") ;
    
    Stream< String > stream = Arrays.stream( array ) ;
    String[] result =
            stream
            .map( ( String s ) -> new StringBuilder( s ).reverse().toString() )
            .toArray(String[]::new) 
    ;
    
    return result ;
}
```

Usage.

```
    String arr[] = { "abc" , "def" , "mask" } ;
    String arr2[] = Ideone.reverse( arr ) ;
    
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString( arr ) ) ;
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString( arr2 ) ) ;
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/0XBDLj).

> [abc, def, mask]
>
> [cba, fed, ksam]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option.  It will work in most versions of Java.  Instead of returning a new Array, it simply modifies the one that is passed.

```
public class ReverseStringsInArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] strArr = {"alpha", "beta","gamma","delta"};
        reversed(strArr);
        for (String v : strArr) {
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }

    public static void reversed(String[] arr) {
        int k = 0;
        for (String v : arr) {
            int[] s = v.codePoints().toArray();
            int len = v.length();
            // swap the outer characters as the pointer moves
            // towards the middle
            for (int i = 0; i < len >> 1; i++) {
                int cp = s[i];
                s[i] = s[len - i - 1];
                s[len - i - 1] = cp;
            }
            arr[k++] = new String(s,0,s.length);
        }
    }
}
```